# Remove the end of a URL string in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to clean and remove the directories from a list of URLs in R

What I have:

```
http://domain.com/123
http://www.sub.domain1.com/222
http://www.domain2.com/1233/abc
```

What I want:

```
domain.com
sub.domain1.com
domain2.com
```

I have a slightly long way to clean the beginning of the URL

```
url <- c("http://domain.com/123", "http://www.sub.domain1.com/222","http://www.domain2.com/1233/abc"

cleanurl <- gsub("http://","",url)
cleanurl2 <- gsub("www.","",cleanurl)
```

(Please let me know if there is a simpler way to clean the http:// and www. too.)

Now I am having problems with the regex and removing everything after the `/` at the end. 
I've tried this

```
cleanurl3 <- gsub("/*","",cleanurl2)
```

But it is just removing the `/` and not everything after it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try using "\/*" (there's a backslash in there). I think the slash should be escaped. See if that works.

Comment: I tried that but its giving me this error > cleanurl3 <- gsub("\/ *","",cleanurl2)
Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\/"

Comment: Your second expression doesn't remove the slash, because `/*` matches any number of `/` characters.  You want `/.*` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I's approach with a `strsplit`/`gsub` combo (not just `gsub` b/c sometimes it's so quick to figure out `strsplit` as it is very intuitive):

```
x <- readLines(n=3)
http://domain.com/123
http://www.sub.domain1.com/222
http://www.domain2.com/1233/abc

gsub("www.", "", sapply(strsplit(x, "//|/"), "[", 2))

## > gsub("www.", "", sapply(strsplit(x, "//|/"), "[", 2))
## [1] "domain.com"      "sub.domain1.com" "domain2.com"
```

**Edit**
Or if you want to just use `strsplit` (per Matthew's suggestion):

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "(//|/)(www[.])?"), "[", 2)
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks for showing the power of R's regular expressions, I just realized that I could improve some of my codes quite a lot with those nice conditionals etc.

Comment: The new strsplit-only answer doesn't remove the `www.`.  How about: `sapply(strsplit(x, "(//|/)(www[.])?"), "[", 2)`

Comment: Good call I'll add it as per your suggestion.  I didn't actually try out my solution.  Should have :)

Answer (score 5):

For the first:

```
cleanurl <- sub("^http://(?:www[.])?(.*)$", "\\1", url)
cleanurl
## [1] "domain.com/123"       "sub.domain1.com/222"  "domain2.com/1233/abc"
```

Just the domains:

```
cleanurl <- sub("^http://(?:www[.])?([^/]*).*$", "\\1", url)
cleanurl
## [1] "domain.com"      "sub.domain1.com" "domain2.com"
```

Comment: Could change the "^http:" to "^https?:" or even generalize to "^[^/]+:" to get ftp, etc. Also, "sub" works as well as "gsub" here (both are vectorized).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
cleanurl <- gsub("http://","",url)
cleanurl2 <- gsub("www.","",cleanurl)

sapply(strsplit(cleanurl2,"/"),"[",1)
[1] "domain.com"      "sub.domain1.com"
[3] "domain2.com"
```

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you! I have one question, why did you use "["? I cant see how that fit in.

Comment: It's a shortcut to indexing as `[` is actually a function of sorts.

Comment: The `"["`is the function which is used by `sapply`. Function `strplit` returns a list, and with `sapply` we extract the first elements of the list components (1 is the argument for "["), so same could be done manually by `x<-strsplit(cleanurl2,"/");c(x[[1]][1],x[[2]][1],x[[3]][1])`