# Function to extract domain name from URL in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a function which can extract the domain name from a URL in R.
Any function which is similar to tldextract in R?
EDIT:
Currently i'm using the below approach:

```
domain=substr(as.character("www.google.com"), 
   which(strsplit("www.google.com",'')[[1]]=='.')[1]+1, nchar("www.google.com"))
```

But i'm looking for a pre-defined function which can save the coding effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove the end of a URL string in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603126/remove-the-end-of-a-url-string-in-r)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of a function in a package to do this.  I don't think there's anything in base install of R.  Use a user defined function and store it some where to `source` later or make your own package with it.

```
x1 <- "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020749/function-to-extract-domain-name-from-url-in-r"
x2 <- "http://www.talkstats.com/"
x3 <- "www.google.com"

domain <- function(x) strsplit(gsub("http://|https://|www\\.", "", x), "/")[[c(1, 1)]]

domain(x3)
sapply(list(x1, x2, x3), domain)
## [1] "stackoverflow.com" "talkstats.com"     "google.com"
```

Comment: This was exactly i was looking for. A function which can handle any possible type of URL.

Answer (score 34):

You can also use the relatively new `urltools` package:

```
library(urltools)

URLs <- c("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020749/function-to-extract-domain-name-from-url-in-r",
          "http://www.talkstats.com/", "www.google.com")

suffix_extract(domain(URLs))

##                host subdomain        domain suffix
## 1 stackoverflow.com      <NA> stackoverflow    com
## 2 www.talkstats.com       www     talkstats    com
## 3    www.google.com       www        google    com
```

It's backed by `Rcpp` so it's wicked fast (significantly more so than using built- in R `apply` functions.

Answer (score 2):

A vectorized option using base R only and customizable super easily in its output could be

```r
url_regexpr <- function() {
  protocol <- "([^/]+://)*"  # could be
  sub <- "([^\\.\\?/]+\\.)*"  # could be
  domain <- "([^\\.\\?/]+)"  # must be
  dot <- "(\\.)"  # must be
  suffix <- "([^/]+)"  # must be
  folders <- "(/[^\\?]*)*"  # could be
  args <- "(\\?.*)*"  #could be

  paste0(
    "^",
    protocol, sub, domain, dot, suffix, folders, args,
    "$"
  )
}

get_domain <- function(url, include_suffix = TRUE) {
  res <- paste0("\\3", c("\\4\\5")[include_suffix])
  sub(url_regexpr(), res, url)
}
```

I have run the following tests on it:

```r
library(testthat)
test_that("get_domain works", {
  expect_equal(get_domain("https://www.example.com"), "example.com")
  expect_equal(get_domain("http://www.example.com"), "example.com")
  expect_equal(get_domain("www.example.com"), "example.com")

  expect_equal(get_domain("www.example.net"), "example.net")
  expect_equal(get_domain("www.example.net/baz"), "example.net")

  expect_equal(get_domain("https://www.example.net/baz"), "example.net")
  expect_equal(get_domain("https://www.example.net/baz/tar"), "example.net")

  expect_equal(get_domain("https://foo.example.net"), "example.net")
  expect_equal(get_domain("https://www.foo.example.net"), "example.net")
})

test_that("get_domain is vectorized", {
  urls <- c("www.example.com", "www.example.net")
  expect_equal(get_domain(urls), c("example.com", "example.net"))
})


test_that("can remove suffix", {
  expect_equal(
    get_domain("https://www.example.com", include_suffix = FALSE),
    "example"
  )
})

test_that("works with file extensions", {
  expect_equal(
    get_domain("https://www.example.com/foo.php"),
    "example.com"
  )
})

test_that("works against leading slash", {
  expect_equal(
    get_domain("http://m.example.com/"),
    "example.com"
  )
})

test_that("works against args after slash", {
  expect_equal(
    get_domain("http://example.com/?"),
    "example.com"
  )
})

test_that("works against multiple dots after slash", {
  expect_equal(
    get_domain("http://example.com/foo.net.bar"),
    "example.com"
  )
})

test_that("generalized protocols", {
  expect_equal(
    get_domain("android-app://example.com/foo.net.bar"),
    "example.com"
  )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this regex which can be applied to emails and websites for extracting and matching on domain. The regex could be modified to extract different parts, and it is vectorized. I do some additional processing which is totally optional.

```html
invalid_domains = "yahoo.com|aol.com|gmail.com|hotmail.com|comcast.net|me.com|att.net|verizon.net|live.com|sbcglobal.net|msn.com|outlook.com|ibm.com"
domain <- function(x){
  to_return <- tolower(as.character(x))
  to_return <- gsub('.*[.@/]+([^.@:/]+[.][a-z]+)(/.*$|$)','\\1',x,ignore.case=T) # extract domain. \\1 selects just the first group.
  to_return <- gsub(".ocm", ".com", to_return) # correct mispellings
  # to_return <- ifelse(grepl(invalid_domains,to_return),NA,to_return) # (optional) check for invalid domains, especially when working with emails.
  to_return <- ifelse(grepl('[.]',to_return),to_return,NA) # if there is no . this is an invalid domain, return NA
  return(to_return)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. You can use this with `dplyr` without slowing your process with `rowwise` or something similar

```
Domain <- function(urls)
{
  urls <- sapply(urls, function(x) httr::parse_url(x)$hostname)
  names(urls) <- NULL
  urls <- stringr::str_remove(urls, ".*www.") ## Keep everything after www.
  return(urls)
}
```