# Extract domain name without suffix or subdomain

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a table which include some domain names

```
    site
1 Google.com
2 yahoo.in
3 facebook.com
4 badge.net
```

So, I want to remove all the words after "." for example ( .com, .net, .in).
 I used below function but that convert my string into numeric form.

```
gsub("\\..*","",df)
```

Comment: The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173754/splitting-a-file-name is not a good close source, because here, the *first* comma is found and all after it is removed. With filepath splitting, the algorithm is different.

Comment: This is maybe also also relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020749/function-to-extract-domain-name-from-url-in-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're working with domain names, so you may want to use some tools that were designed to do so:

```
library(urltools)

df <- data.frame(site=c("Google.com", "yahoo.in", "facebook.com", "badge.net"))

suffix_extract(df$site)
##           host subdomain   domain suffix
## 1   Google.com      <NA>   google    com
## 2     yahoo.in      <NA>    yahoo     in
## 3 facebook.com      <NA> facebook    com
## 4    badge.net      <NA>    badge    net
```

for @Sotos:

```
urltools::suffix_extract('www.bankofcyprus.com')
##                   host subdomain       domain suffix
## 1 www.bankofcyprus.com       www bankofcyprus    com
```

Comment: yup, Thanks i only need domain but now i can extract it from this solution.