# Extracting substring from string if pattern varies

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, substring, stringr

I would like to extract names from weblinks using *substr()*. My problem is that the patterns vary slightly, so I am not sure how to account for the variances. Here is a sample:

INPUT:

```
list <- c("https://www.gatcoin.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/GATCOIN-Whitepaper_ENG-1.pdf",
"https://appcoins.io/pdf/appcoins_whitepaper.pdf",
"https://pareto.network/download/Pareto-Technical-White-Paper.pdf",
"http://betbox.ai/BetBoxBizWhitepaper.pdf",
"https://www.aidcoin.co/assets/documents/whitepaper.pdf")
```

What I want as Output

```
c("gatcoin", "appcoins", "pareto", "betbox", "aidcoin")
```

In my understanding I need to specify the start and end of the string to be extracted, but sometimes start would be "https://", while other times it would be "https://www."

How could I solve this?

Comment: @smci How do you know OP knows about regexes...?

Comment: @akraf: I thought that OP tagged this regex and was asking for someone to write a regex. But regardless, where is any attempted code with substr, strsplit or anything else? SO requires users to make an attempt, and typically to show some attempted code

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020749/function-to-extract-domain-name-from-url-in-r

Comment: @smic: well, this is an encouraging way to respond to users who are just starting to learn coding language. Also, not very helpful ;-). I did not know about regrex, if that answers your doubts.

Comment: Based on the link of @zx8754: `library(urltools); suffix_extract(domain(urls))$domain` where `urls` is the vector of links.

Comment: @Carolin: welcome to SO. I did recommend you look into regex, and I told you how to build the regex. In general you are required to show some code attempt (even with substr or strsplit or whatever), otherwise your question is likely to get deleted or downvoted, and I was trying to help you avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with `stringr`...

```
library(stringr)

str_match(list, "\\/(www\\.)*(\\w+)\\.")[,3]

[1] "gatcoin"  "appcoins" "pareto"   "betbox"   "aidcoin"
```

The regex extracts the first sequence of letters between a slash and an optional `www.`, and the next dot.

The equivalent in base R is slightly messier...

```
sub(".+?\\/(?:www\\.)*(\\w+)\\..+", "\\1", list)
```

This adds the start and end of the string as well, replacing the whole lot with just the capture group you want.  It sets the optional `www.` as a non-capturing group, as `sub` and `str_match` behave differently if the first group is not found.

Answer (score 1):

```
list <- c("https://www.gatcoin.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/GATCOIN- Whitepaper_ENG-1.pdf", 
          "https://appcoins.io/pdf/appcoins_whitepaper.pdf", 
          "https://pareto.network/download/Pareto-Technical-White-Paper.pdf", 
          "http://betbox.ai/BetBoxBizWhitepaper.pdf", 
          "https://www.aidcoin.co/assets/documents/whitepaper.pdf")
pattern <- c("https://", "www.", "http://")
for(p in pattern) list <- gsub(p, "", list)
unlist(lapply(strsplit(list, "[.]"), function(x) x[1]))
[1] "gatcoin"  "appcoins" "pareto"   "betbox"   "aidcoin"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Regular Expressions](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html). However, that is reinventing the wheel. People have thought about how to split URLs before so use an already existing function.

For example `parse_url` of the httr package. Or google "R parse URL" for alternatives.

```
urls <- list("https://www.gatcoin.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/GATCOIN-Whitepaper_ENG-1.pdf",
"https://appcoins.io/pdf/appcoins_whitepaper.pdf",
"https://pareto.network/download/Pareto-Technical-White-Paper.pdf",
"http://betbox.ai/BetBoxBizWhitepaper.pdf",
"https://www.aidcoin.co/assets/documents/whitepaper.pdf")
```

Use `lapply` to use `parse_url` for every element of `urls`

```
 parsed <- lapply(urls, httr::parse_url)
```

Now you have a list of lists. Each element of the list `parsed` has multiple elements itself which contain the parts of the URL`.

Extract all the elements `parsed[[...]]$hostname`:

```
hostname <- sapply(parsed, function(e) e$hostname)
```

Split those by the dot and take the second last element:

```
domain <- strsplit(hostname, "\\.")
domain <- sapply(domain, function(d) d[length(d)-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This Regex captures the word after the `://(www.)` .

```
(?::\/\/(?:www.)?)(\w+)
```